# Не получается установить расширение Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь установить расширение socialiteproviders/vkontakte.

Выполняю команду:

```
composer require socialiteproviders/vkontakte
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content
```

Подскажите, куда смотреть надо?

На всякий случай сообщения выше:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
 - Installation request for socialiteproviders/vkontakte ^3.0 -> satisfiable by socialiteproviders/vkontakte[v3.0.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.1.45
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.45
- socialiteproviders/vkontakte v3.0.0 requires socialiteproviders/manager ~3.0 -> satisfiable by socialiteproviders/manager[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4].
- socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.0 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].
- socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.1 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].
- socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.2 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].
- socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.3 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].
- socialiteproviders/manager v3.0.4 requires laravel/socialite ~3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].
- laravel/socialite 3.0.x-dev requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
- laravel/socialite 3.0.x-dev requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
- laravel/socialite v3.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
- laravel/socialite v3.0.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
- laravel/socialite v3.0.3 requires illuminate/support ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
- don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.45
- don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.45
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.45
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.45
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.45
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.1.45, required as 5.1.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.45].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня в пустую папку встал без проблем.
Судя по сообщениям, проблема связана с настройками Composer в ранее установленном Laravel.
Попробуйте сперва выполнить шаг 2 из настроек расширения:

> 2. SERVICE PROVIDER
>
> Удалить Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider из массива 
>   providers[] в config\app.php, если он там был (наверное был).
>
> Добавить \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class к массиву 
>   providers[] в config\app.php.
>
> Например:

```
'providers' => [
    // a whole bunch of providers
    // remove 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider',
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class, // add
];
```

http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/vkontakte/#service-provider